# How do I run a Ruby Gem via the Sublime Text 2 Build System?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sublimetext2

I've tried different settings like simply:

```
{
  "cmd": "rubocop '$file_name'"
}
```

I've also tried setting the path, etc:

```
{
  "cmd": "rubocop '$file_name'",
  "path": "~/.rvm/bin",
  "selector": "source.rb",
  "working_dir":"$project_path"
}
```

For both I get an error message along the lines of:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  rubocop 'configurer.rb']
[dir:  /home/rafal/Documents/Projects/configurer]
[path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]
[Finished]
```

and:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  rubocop 'configurer.rb']
[dir:  /home/rafal/Documents/Projects/configurer]
[path: ~/.rvm/bin]
[Finished]
```

respectively. I have followed some of the tutorials I've found online as well as some of the answers here at StackOverflow but no luck. Any ideas on why this is happening? What is the correct and working way of running a Ruby Gem upon a currently open file? The Gem [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) is definitely installed.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. I wonder why nobody has answered it yet.

Answer (score 3):

I made the custom build work on SublimeText2 with

```
{
  "env": {
    "PATH":"${HOME}/.rvm/bin:${PATH}"
  },
  "cmd": ["rvm-auto-ruby", "-S", "bundle", "exec", "rubocop -n ${file}" ],
  "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

Note that the `-n` option of rubocop was [introduced 5 days ago](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commit/e4db90782565610235b11b580536751a6539584c) in the repo (after the 0.6.1 release), so it probably won't work if you don't use the rubocop from the [git repo](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop). Until 0.6.2 is released, it will display weird chars in the output, but at least it will work.

Comment: Why does the OPs solution not work i.e. "cmd": "rubocop ${file}", it works from the terminal?

Comment: In the terminal your environment (from bashrc or zshrc or profile) is set to know how to run ruby. In sublime text you need to be more explicit because this environment is not loaded.